# Meteor/NodeJS with MongoDB Replica Sets - Multiple Datacenter Secondaries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I am running Meteor (NodeJS) and planning to point to to multiple copies of MongoDB running in separate datacenters.  I plan to use:

MONGO_URL="mongodb://server1:27017,server2:27017,server3:27017,server4:27017/dbname?replicaSet=rs1&readPreference=nearest&w=majority"

Two questions.

1) Does anyone know if this will tell Node/Meteor to get its database read requests from the MongoDB that is CLOSEST (quickest ping times)? I think it should, according to the MongoDB docs, "nearest" readPreference https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/ but I can't find the answer for sure in the Meteor and Node docs.

2) If the closest MongoDB disappears or times-out, will it automatically failover the database read requests to the next-closest Mongo?

Comment: This is an interesting one. I don't even know if Meteor handle an automatic failover. From my experience, I don't even manage to make a Meteor app auto reconnect to Mongo (single instance) after a server freeze (Azure hosting mhe...). So I'm a little worried about more advanced concept. See this issue https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4600#issuecomment-236122928